# unable to deploy kubernetes with DNS on a local ubuntu cluster (so one node)

Tags: ubuntu, dns, kubernetes

unable to deploy kubernetes with DNS on a local ubuntu cluster (so one node). I think it may have to do with flannel however I am not sure and more importantly I am not sure why it points at coreos when I am trying to deploy on ubuntu. I had to change some stuff in config-default.sh under cluster/ubuntu for me to even get this however this one error I am unable to resolve and finally unable to launch kubernetes with dns.

Below is my error trace. I am not sure if the following lines from the error trace below is the reason why I wasn't able to deploy kube-up.sh

```
Error: 100: Key not found (/coreos.com) [1]
{"Network":"172.16.0.0/16", "Backend": {"Type": "vxlan"}}
{"Network":"172.16.0.0/16", "Backend": {"Type": "vxlan"}}
```

---

```
ERROR TRACE

$KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh // ran this command on terminal
... Starting cluster using provider: ubuntu
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling kube-up
~/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu ~/kubernetes/cluster
Prepare flannel 0.5.0 release ...
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
100 608 0 608 0 0 102 0 --:--:-- 0:00:05 --:--:-- 138
100 2757k 100 2757k 0 0 194k 0 0:00:14 0:00:14 --:--:-- 739k
Prepare etcd 2.2.0 release ...
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
100 606 0 606 0 0 101 0 --:--:-- 0:00:05 --:--:-- 175
100 7183k 100 7183k 0 0 468k 0 0:00:15 0:00:15 --:--:-- 1871k
Prepare kubernetes 1.2.4 release ...
Done! All your binaries locate in kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries directory
~/kubernetes/cluster

Deploying master and node on machine 192.168.245.244
make-ca-cert.sh 100% 4028 3.9KB/s 00:00

easy-rsa.tar.gz 100% 42KB 42.4KB/s 00:00

config-default.sh 100% 5419 5.3KB/s 00:00

util.sh 100% 29KB 28.6KB/s 00:00

kubelet.conf 100% 644 0.6KB/s 00:00

kube-proxy.conf 100% 684 0.7KB/s 00:00

kubelet 100% 2158 2.1KB/s 00:00

kube-proxy 100% 2233 2.2KB/s 00:00

kube-scheduler.conf 100% 674 0.7KB/s 00:00

etcd.conf 100% 709 0.7KB/s 00:00

kube-controller-manager.conf 100% 744 0.7KB/s 00:00

kube-apiserver.conf 100% 674 0.7KB/s 00:00

kube-apiserver 100% 2358 2.3KB/s 00:00

kube-scheduler 100% 2360 2.3KB/s 00:00

kube-controller-manager 100% 2672 2.6KB/s 00:00

etcd 100% 2073 2.0KB/s 00:00

reconfDocker.sh 100% 2094 2.0KB/s 00:00

kube-apiserver 100% 58MB 58.2MB/s 00:00

kube-scheduler 100% 42MB 42.0MB/s 00:00

kube-controller-manager 100% 52MB 51.8MB/s 00:00

etcdctl 100% 12MB 12.3MB/s 00:00

etcd 100% 14MB 13.8MB/s 00:00

flanneld 100% 11MB 10.8MB/s 00:00

kubelet 100% 60MB 60.3MB/s 00:01

kube-proxy 100% 35MB 34.8MB/s 00:00

flanneld 100% 11MB 10.8MB/s 00:00

flanneld.conf 100% 577 0.6KB/s 00:00

flanneld 100% 2121 2.1KB/s 00:00

flanneld.conf 100% 568 0.6KB/s 00:00

flanneld 100% 2131 2.1KB/s 00:00

[sudo] password to start master: // I entered my password manually
etcd start/running, process 100639
Error: 100: Key not found (/coreos.com) [1]
{"Network":"172.16.0.0/16", "Backend": {"Type": "vxlan"}}
{"Network":"172.16.0.0/16", "Backend": {"Type": "vxlan"}}
docker stop/waiting
docker start/running, process 101035
Connection to 192.168.245.244 closed.
Validating master
Validating kant@192.168.245.244
Using master 192.168.245.244
cluster "ubuntu" set.
user "ubuntu" set.
context "ubuntu" set.
switched to context "ubuntu".
Wrote config for ubuntu to /home/kant/.kube/config
... calling validate-cluster
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
```

Here is the error trace when I turn the debug flag to true in config-default.sh

```
$ KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh
... Starting cluster using provider: ubuntu
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling kube-up
~/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu ~/kubernetes/cluster
Prepare flannel 0.5.5 release ...
Prepare etcd 2.3.1 release ...
Prepare kubernetes 1.2.4 release ...
Done! All your binaries locate in kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries directory
~/kubernetes/cluster

Deploying master and node on machine 192.168.245.237
make-ca-cert.sh                                                                                 100% 4028     3.9KB/s   00:00    
easy-rsa.tar.gz                                                                                 100%   42KB  42.4KB/s   00:00    
config-default.sh                                                                               100% 5474     5.4KB/s   00:00    
util.sh                                                                                         100%   29KB  28.6KB/s   00:00    
kubelet.conf                                                                                    100%  644     0.6KB/s   00:00    
kube-proxy.conf                                                                                 100%  684     0.7KB/s   00:00    
kubelet                                                                                         100% 2158     2.1KB/s   00:00    
kube-proxy                                                                                      100% 2233     2.2KB/s   00:00    
kube-scheduler.conf                                                                             100%  674     0.7KB/s   00:00    
etcd.conf                                                                                       100%  709     0.7KB/s   00:00    
kube-controller-manager.conf                                                                    100%  744     0.7KB/s   00:00    
kube-apiserver.conf                                                                             100%  674     0.7KB/s   00:00    
kube-apiserver                                                                                  100% 2358     2.3KB/s   00:00    
kube-scheduler                                                                                  100% 2360     2.3KB/s   00:00    
kube-controller-manager                                                                         100% 2672     2.6KB/s   00:00    
etcd                                                                                            100% 2073     2.0KB/s   00:00    
reconfDocker.sh                                                                                 100% 2094     2.0KB/s   00:00    
kube-apiserver                                                                                  100%   58MB  58.2MB/s   00:01    
kube-scheduler                                                                                  100%   42MB  42.0MB/s   00:00    
kube-controller-manager                                                                         100%   52MB  51.8MB/s   00:00    
etcdctl                                                                                         100%   14MB  13.7MB/s   00:00    
etcd                                                                                            100%   16MB  15.9MB/s   00:00    
flanneld                                                                                        100%   16MB  15.8MB/s   00:00    
kubelet                                                                                         100%   60MB  60.3MB/s   00:01    
kube-proxy                                                                                      100%   35MB  34.8MB/s   00:00    
flanneld                                                                                        100%   16MB  15.8MB/s   00:00    
flanneld.conf                                                                                   100%  577     0.6KB/s   00:00    
flanneld                                                                                        100% 2121     2.1KB/s   00:00    
flanneld.conf                                                                                   100%  568     0.6KB/s   00:00    
flanneld                                                                                        100% 2131     2.1KB/s   00:00    
+ source /home/kant/kube/util.sh
++ set -e
++ SSH_OPTS='-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oLogLevel=ERROR'
++ MASTER=
++ MASTER_IP=
++ NODE_IPS=
+ setClusterInfo
+ NODE_IPS=
+ local ii=0
+ create-etcd-opts 192.168.245.237
+ cat
+ create-kube-apiserver-opts 192.168.3.0/24 NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,SecurityContextDeny,ResourceQuota 30000-32767 192.168.245.237
+ cat
+ create-kube-controller-manager-opts 192.168.245.237
+ cat
+ create-kube-scheduler-opts
+ cat
+ create-kubelet-opts 192.168.245.237 192.168.245.237 192.168.3.10 cluster.local '' ''
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ cni_opts=
+ cat
+ create-kube-proxy-opts 192.168.245.237 192.168.245.237 ''
+ cat
+ create-flanneld-opts 127.0.0.1 192.168.245.237
+ cat
+ FLANNEL_OTHER_NET_CONFIG=
+ sudo -E -p '[sudo] password to start master: ' -- /bin/bash -ce ' 
      set -x
      cp ~/kube/default/* /etc/default/
      cp ~/kube/init_conf/* /etc/init/
      cp ~/kube/init_scripts/* /etc/init.d/

      groupadd -f -r kube-cert
       DEBUG=true ~/kube/make-ca-cert.sh "192.168.245.237" "IP:192.168.245.237,IP:192.168.3.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local"
      mkdir -p /opt/bin/
      cp ~/kube/master/* /opt/bin/
      cp ~/kube/minion/* /opt/bin/

      service etcd start
      if true; then FLANNEL_NET="172.16.0.0/16" KUBE_CONFIG_FILE="./../cluster/../cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh" DOCKER_OPTS="" ~/kube/reconfDocker.sh ai; fi
      '
[sudo] password to start master: 
+ cp /home/kant/kube/default/etcd /home/kant/kube/default/flanneld /home/kant/kube/default/kube-apiserver /home/kant/kube/default/kube-controller-manager /home/kant/kube/default/kubelet /home/kant/kube/default/kube-proxy /home/kant/kube/default/kube-scheduler /etc/default/
+ cp /home/kant/kube/init_conf/etcd.conf /home/kant/kube/init_conf/flanneld.conf /home/kant/kube/init_conf/kube-apiserver.conf /home/kant/kube/init_conf/kube-controller-manager.conf /home/kant/kube/init_conf/kubelet.conf /home/kant/kube/init_conf/kube-proxy.conf /home/kant/kube/init_conf/kube-scheduler.conf /etc/init/
+ cp /home/kant/kube/init_scripts/etcd /home/kant/kube/init_scripts/flanneld /home/kant/kube/init_scripts/kube-apiserver /home/kant/kube/init_scripts/kube-controller-manager /home/kant/kube/init_scripts/kubelet /home/kant/kube/init_scripts/kube-proxy /home/kant/kube/init_scripts/kube-scheduler /etc/init.d/
+ groupadd -f -r kube-cert
+ DEBUG=true
+ /home/kant/kube/make-ca-cert.sh 192.168.245.237 IP:192.168.245.237,IP:192.168.3.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
+ cert_ip=192.168.245.237
+ extra_sans=IP:192.168.245.237,IP:192.168.3.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
+ cert_dir=/srv/kubernetes
+ cert_group=kube-cert
+ mkdir -p /srv/kubernetes
+ use_cn=false
+ '[' 192.168.245.237 == _use_gce_external_ip_ ']'
+ '[' 192.168.245.237 == _use_aws_external_ip_ ']'
+ sans=IP:192.168.245.237
+ [[ -n IP:192.168.245.237,IP:192.168.3.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local ]]
+ sans=IP:192.168.245.237,IP:192.168.245.237,IP:192.168.3.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
++ mktemp -d -t kubernetes_cacert.XXXXXX
+ tmpdir=/tmp/kubernetes_cacert.YAN8Jg
+ trap 'rm -rf "${tmpdir}"' EXIT
+ cd /tmp/kubernetes_cacert.YAN8Jg
+ '[' -f /home/kant/kube/easy-rsa.tar.gz ']'
+ ln -s /home/kant/kube/easy-rsa.tar.gz .
+ tar xzf easy-rsa.tar.gz
+ cd easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3
+ ./easyrsa init-pki
++ date +%s
+ ./easyrsa --batch --req-cn=192.168.245.237@1465788589 build-ca nopass
+ '[' false = true ']'
+ ./easyrsa --subject-alt-name=IP:192.168.245.237,IP:192.168.245.237,IP:192.168.3.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local build-server-full kubernetes-master nopass
+ cp -p pki/issued/kubernetes-master.crt /srv/kubernetes/server.cert
+ cp -p pki/private/kubernetes-master.key /srv/kubernetes/server.key
+ ./easyrsa build-client-full kubecfg nopass
+ cp -p pki/ca.crt /srv/kubernetes/ca.crt
+ cp -p pki/issued/kubecfg.crt /srv/kubernetes/kubecfg.crt
+ cp -p pki/private/kubecfg.key /srv/kubernetes/kubecfg.key
+ chgrp kube-cert /srv/kubernetes/server.key /srv/kubernetes/server.cert /srv/kubernetes/ca.crt
+ chmod 660 /srv/kubernetes/server.key /srv/kubernetes/server.cert /srv/kubernetes/ca.crt
+ rm -rf /tmp/kubernetes_cacert.YAN8Jg
+ mkdir -p /opt/bin/
+ cp /home/kant/kube/master/etcd /home/kant/kube/master/etcdctl /home/kant/kube/master/flanneld /home/kant/kube/master/kube-apiserver /home/kant/kube/master/kube-controller-manager /home/kant/kube/master/kube-scheduler /opt/bin/
+ cp /home/kant/kube/minion/flanneld /home/kant/kube/minion/kubelet /home/kant/kube/minion/kube-proxy /opt/bin/
+ service etcd start
etcd start/running, process 74611
+ true
+ FLANNEL_NET=172.16.0.0/16
+ KUBE_CONFIG_FILE=./../cluster/../cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh
+ DOCKER_OPTS=
+ /home/kant/kube/reconfDocker.sh ai
Error:  100: Key not found (/coreos.com) [1]
{"Network":"172.16.0.0/16", "Backend": {"Type": "vxlan"}}
{"Network":"172.16.0.0/16", "Backend": {"Type": "vxlan"}}
docker stop/waiting
docker start/running, process 75022
Connection to 192.168.245.237 closed.
Validating master
Validating kant@192.168.245.237
Using master 192.168.245.237
cluster "ubuntu" set.
user "ubuntu" set.
context "ubuntu" set.
switched to context "ubuntu".
Wrote config for ubuntu to /home/kant/.kube/config
... calling validate-cluster
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 1 ready nodes. 0 ready nodes, 0 registered. Retrying.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have incorrect config in config-default.sh.
If you wanted to deploy local cluster in a node (with both master and worker), you would config file config-default.sh with:

```
roles=${roles:-"ai"}
```

and

```
export NUM_NODES=${NUM_NODES:-1}
```

Value of ***NUM_NODES*** is number of ***i*** in ***roles***

Comment: Hi I had exactly those I just made sure. This time I also ran with turn on the debug flag and I have added more info on my question. I have been trying to solve this for a week but I am unable to get this right. I suspect it has to do something with flannel however I am not 100% sure as I am new to kubernetes as well.

Comment: oh, I had same issue with you in first time I deploy Kubernetes Cluster. But when i changed value of $NUMNODE to 1, it's work. Then i don't know why you still get error.